# Audio RSS from YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api, rss, podcast

Whether it possible to create podcast RSS from YouTube channel?

Does YouTube have some API for this?

Also whether it possible to get audio from specific YouTube video?

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe so, but Google does have documentation for the Youtube API.

I did not find much in the docs about just interacting with the audio, but here's the docs commmon use cases: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets